# How can I user the select option values as the source of from in a mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Checa y Actualiza precios</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Checador Laborcilla">
    <meta name="Francisco Moncada" content="Catalogo">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">

    </div>
    <div class="botones">
      <!--Seleccion-->
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <select name="productos">
          <option value="cat_carne">Carne</option>
          <option value="cat_pescado_mariscos">Pescado y Mariscos</option>
          <option value="cat_aves">Aves</option>
          <option value="cat_varios">Varios</option>
          <option value="cat_abarrotes">Abarrotes</option>
          <option value="cat_congelados">Congelados</option>
          <option value="cat_fruta_verdura">Frutas y Verduras</option>
          <option value="cat_lacteos">Lacteos</option>
          <option value="cat_destilados">Destilados</option>
          <option value="cat_vinos">Vinos</option>
          <option value="cat_cerveza">Cerveza</option>
          <option value="cat_refrescos">Refrescos</option>
          <option value="cat_mezclador">Mezclador</option>
          <option value="cat_cafe">Café</option>
          <option value="cat_te">Té</option>
          <option value="cat_cigarros">Cigarros</option>
          
      </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        <?php $producto = $_POST['productos']; echo $producto; ?>
       <!--Dropdown-->
        <?php
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "francisco";
        $password = "";
        $db = "insumos";
        $connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username , $password, $db);
        
         if ($connection->connect_error){
                die("Database connection failed: " .$connection->connect_error);
            }
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tabla">
        <!--Tabla de productos -->
        <table>
            <tr class="theader">
                <th>Subtipo</th>
                <th>Prodcutos</th>
                <th>Proveedor</th>
                <th>Costo_nov</th>
                <th>Costo2_nov</th>
                <th>Costo_oct</th>
                <th>Costo2_oct</th>
                <th>Porcentaje_aumento</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
if ($connection->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}
$sql = "select
                cc.subtipo as subtipo
              , prd.productos as productos
              , pro.proveedor as proveedor
              , cc.costo_unitario_nov_19 as costo_nov
              , cc.costo_lt_kg_nov_19 as costo2_nov
              , cc.costo_unitario_oct_19 as costo_oct
              , cc.costo_lt_kg_oct_19 as costo2_oct
              , round((((cc.costo_unitario_nov_19 - cc.costo_unitario_oct_19) / cc.costo_unitario_nov_19)*100), 2)as Porcentaje_Aumento
from          
                <!--need to change this part --> cat_carne cc
                left outer join
                productos prd on                                           cc.id_producto = prd.id_prod
                left outer join
                proveedores pro on
                cc.id_proveedores = pro.id_proveedores";
                
$result = $connection->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["subtipo"]. "</td><td>" . $row["productos"] . "</td><td>". $row["proveedor"]. "</td><td>" . $row["costo_nov"]. "</td><td>" . $row["costo2_nov"]. "</td><td>" . $row["costo_oct"]. "</td><td>" . $row["costo2_oct"]. "</td><td>". $row["Porcentaje_Aumento"]. "</td></tr>" ;
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$connection->close();
?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

How can I use the values of the select to change in the query so the form show me different information on my table?

I have tried with post but I get an array to string error.

I have also made the dropdown menu get the information from the database but it made things more complicated.

**UPDATE

I have managed to see the POST information and I'm getting the Select options as expected but still I can't find a way to use the $_POST info to use it on the FROM part of mysql statement.

Comment: It is unclear what part of the query you want to replace with the submitted value.  But your first step should be to research mysqli's [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the concatenation wrong I used ".$productos." and it worked! Thanks!